# Getting "incorrectly aligned or overlapped by non-object" error on explicit struct

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling

I'm trying to read/edit Diablo's save file. Specification [here](http://code.componentix.com/diablo2exp/Save_File_Format.xhtml), if anyone's interested, but I dont think it is relevant to the question.

I have a byte array with the file bytes that i'm trying to parse to some structs. I can already read the file header fine, btu im having trouble with the quests data. I got there structs:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 10, Pack = 1)]
public struct QuestCompletationDataHeader {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public string Identifier;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    uint _0x0004;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    short _0x008;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 96, Pack = 1)]
public struct QuestData {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 96, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    byte[] _0x0000; //Irrelevant for now.
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 298, Pack = 1)]
public struct QuestCompletationData {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    QuestCompletationDataHeader Header;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    [FieldOffset(10)]
    QuestData NormalQuests;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    [FieldOffset(106)]
    QuestData NightmareQuests;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    [FieldOffset(202)]
    QuestData HellQuests;

}
```

The D2SFile class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 638, Pack = 1)]
public struct D2SFile {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public D2SHeader Header;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    [FieldOffset(335)]
    public QuestCompletationData Quests;
}
```

And the function Im using to do the byte to struct conversion:

```
 public static D2SFile ByteArrayToD2SFile(byte[] bytes) {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        D2SFile stuff = (D2SFile)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(D2SFile));
        handle.Free();
        return stuff;
    }
```

As I said, I can already read the file header alone without a problem, but when I add the quest data to the D2SFile struct I get: `Could not load type 'MedianXLEditor.QuestCompletationData' from assembly '...' because it contains an object field at offset 10 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.`

Answer (score 9):

Since no one answered and I already found out what was wrong I think I should answer it myself so that anyone that happens to end up here after googling have a easier time.

It turns out you cant have a array starting at offsets that are not multiples of 4.

On the example above, the `QuestCompletationDataHeader` is 10 bytes long, so on the `QuestCompletationData` struct the next field will start at position 10. The next field happens to be of the `QuestData` struct which is basically a big array (for now). So it will try to place that array at the offset 10, 10 is not a multiple of 4 so it gives the exception.

I changed the `QuestData` struct so it does not use a array on the first position and it works fine now.

Also, use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]` when Marshalling structs like the ones above. I was using `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]` which gave me another exception later.

Comment: How on earth did you figure that out?

Comment: here some man also mentioned it. And for him the main problem was the Explicit struct layout. So after change to Sequentional the error disappeared. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2f9ffce5-4c64-4ea7-a994-06b372b28c39/strange-issue-with-layoutkindexplicit?forum=clr